# Bounds for the $2$-torsion subgroup of the class group of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am looking for nontrivial bounds on the sizes of the $2$-torsion subgroups of the class groups of cubic and higher degree number fields $K$. The entire class group is bounded in size by $O(|\text{disc}(K)|^{\frac 12+\epsilon})$.

The suggested answer has nothing to do with this.

Should I look for bounds of Brumer and Kramer on the sizes of $2$-Selmer groups and ranks of elliptic curves, or bounds of Helfgott and Venkatesh on the number of integral points on elliptic curves, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent work of [Bhargava, Shankar, Taniguchi, Thorne, Tsimerman, and Zhao](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02458.pdf) shows that if $K$ is a number field of degree $n$ then the size of the $2$-torsion subgroup of the class group of $K$ is
$$ 
O(|\text{disc}(K)|^{1/2-\delta_n +\epsilon}),
$$
where $\delta_n=1/(2n)$ is permissible.  For cubic and quartic fields, stronger bounds are obtained.  The case of quadratic fields is trivial by genus theory.

Comment: Given the other efforts of this user on MO: the question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243876/2-torsion-in-class-groups-of-cubic-fields and the answers there may be relevant

Comment: @YemonChoi: By "this user" presumably you mean the OP and not me! :)  I hadn't realized that the other question exists, and this can clearly be closed as a duplicate (which I think I can do single-handedly!).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have started that previous comment with "Dear Lucia" ... :)
I only just noticed the older question in the sidebar, because the sophistication of the present question seemed slightly at odds with https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370947/could-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-too-trivial-to-solve and some separate interactions I had with the same user

Comment: Dear Lucia: I have flagged the original question, since I increasingly believe it was not asked in good faith, especially looking at the original version before you cleaned up the punctuation and formatting